# Wordpress Custom Taxonomy for On Line Tour Operator

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy

I'm thinking of migrating the site I work for (www.portalesardegna.com) on wordpress, given the potential it offers. First, however, I would strongly consider the possibility to customize the standard taxonomy of wordpress to do so that it can adapt to the current taxonomy of my site, for example, I would like to create a taxonomy of this kind:

Site root http://www.portalesardegna.com

Accomodation List

Lev 1

```
/hotel/
/holiday-houses/
/residence/
/villas/
/resorts/
```

Lev 2a

```
/n_stars/
```

Lev 2b

```
/zone_name/
/city_name/
```

URL examples:

```
http://www.portalesardegna.com/hotel/3-stars/
http://www.portalesardegna.com/hotel/3-stars/zone_name/
http://www.portalesardegna.com/hotel/3-stars/city_name/
http://www.portalesardegna.com/hotel/zone_name/
http://www.portalesardegna.com/hotel/city_name/
```

E' possibile creare una tassonomia del genere tramite un plugin? Oppure esiste qualche altro modo per personalizzare in questo modo la tassonomia?

Is it possible to create a taxonomy like this through a plugin? Or there is some other way to customize in this way the taxonomy?

Comment: please post your answer in english

Comment: Sorry, the force of habit!!!